Cereal archive called from DLL cause polymorphism not to work
I am a newbie to cereal and lately I ran into an odd issue,
I have my serialization code inside an external DLL, in the code I use cereal's polymorphism functionality, when trying to invoke the archive() method that is in the DLL from the executable, the program crashes, this however only happens if the archive() method is called from compiled code (I suspect), if it is visible to the caller (called directly by the main function) there is no crash,
also if I disable the polymorphic usage there is no crash,
also if I change the DLL to be a Static lib there is no crash.
the crash is caused by an UNREGISTERED_POLYMORPHIC_EXCEPTION. it specifies that I need to register the polymorphic type and it seems to not be present in the binding map although I register it in advance.
I devised a small example to demonstrate the issue:
I am using Windows 10 MSVC 2022
cereal v1.3.2
In External DLL
Archiver.hpp
#pragma once

#include <cereal/archives/xml.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/polymorphic.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/vector.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "myclasses.hpp"

class __declspec(dllexport) Archiver
{
public:
    void add(std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> cls)
    {
        classes.push_back(cls);
    }

    void save()
    {
        std::ofstream os("polymorphism_test.xml");
        cereal::XMLOutputArchive oarchive(os);

        oarchive(classes);
    }

    void load()
    {
        {
            std::ifstream is("polymorphism_test.xml");
            cereal::XMLInputArchive iarchive(is);

            std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>> ptrs;
            iarchive(ptrs);

            //ptrs[0]->sayType();  
            ptrs[0]->sayType();
        }
    }
    

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>> classes;
};

IndirectCaller.hpp
#pragma once

struct BaseClass;

#include <memory>

class __declspec(dllexport) indirectCaller
{
public:
    void call(std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> cls);
};

IndirectCaller.cpp
#include "indirectCaller.hpp"

#include "archiver.hpp"

void indirectCaller::call(std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> cls)
{
    Archiver a;
    a.add(cls);
    a.save();
    a.load();
}


myclasses.hpp
#pragma once

// Include the polymorphic serialization and registration mechanisms
#include <cereal/types/polymorphic.hpp>

 // A pure virtual base class
struct BaseClass
{
    virtual void sayType() = 0;
};

In Executable
NewDerived.hpp
#pragma once

// Include the polymorphic serialization and registration mechanisms
#include <cereal/types/polymorphic.hpp>

#include "myclasses.hpp"

// A class derived from BaseClass
struct DerivedClassThree : public BaseClass
{
    void sayType()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived 3" << std::endl;
    }

    int x;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar)
    {
        ar(x);
    }
};
#include <cereal/archives/binary.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/xml.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/json.hpp>

CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE(DerivedClassThree);
CEREAL_REGISTER_POLYMORPHIC_RELATION(BaseClass, DerivedClassThree)

main.cpp

#include "myclasses.hpp"

#include <cereal/archives/xml.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/polymorphic.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "newderived.hpp"

#include "indirectCaller.hpp"

int main()
{
    indirectCaller a;
    a.call(std::make_shared<DerivedClassThree>());

    return 0;
}


The issue is that you don't have the polymorphic registration code for the derived class at the point of serialization, when IndirectCaller.cpp is in a dll.
What cereal is doing when you call CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE(T) is it creates a bunch of global StaticObject<> instances that register that type with all reigstered/included archives. If you have a dynamic library, these global objects are not shared between the dll and the executable - each will have its own set of registered polymorphic objects.
You need to perform the serialization in a context where all the archvives and all types are registered. If you are registering a base class in a dynamic library and the derived class in a executable, this means the Archiver code must be called directly from the executable.
